# Generating Gaussian Samples

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose we generate $N$ indepedent $2D$ Gaussian samples from $
  X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\Sigma)\,
$ and put it into a matrix $A$. Therefore $A$ is $2$x$N$ matrix. Now if I get the first row of this matrix, will it be a Gaussian? When I plot the histogram of the vector, it seems a Gaussian but I want to convince myself theoretically. How can I show this theoretically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will be Gaussian. By taking the first row only, you are taking the first marginal distribution of the multivariate Gaussian. The multivariate Gaussian distribution has the following property (and sometimes it is even the definition):

> Let $X$ be a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then, $X$ is multivariate Gaussian if and only if every one-dimensional marginal distribution $a'X$ is univariate Gaussian, where $a = (a_1, \ldots, a_d)' \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Now in the above result just take $d = 2$ and $a = (1, 0)'$. This will get you your theoretical result. Hope this helps!

Comment: What will be the mean and variance of the first row in terms of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$?

Comment: In general, we have $a'X \sim \mathcal{N}(a'\mu, a'\Sigma a)$. In your case, the mean will simply be the first component of $\mu$ and the variance will be the $(1,1)$ element of $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

$$X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\Sigma)\,$$

$X=\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix}, \mu=\begin{pmatrix} \mu_x \\ \mu_y \end{pmatrix}$, and $\Sigma$ is symmetric and can always be expressed as $$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_x^2 & \rho \sigma_x \sigma_y \\ \rho \sigma_x \sigma_y & \sigma_y^2\end{pmatrix}.$$
Thus
$$\displaystyle f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi |\Sigma|^{1/2}} \exp \left[ - \frac{(X-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (X-\mu) }{2} \right]$$ so that

$$\displaystyle f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_x \sigma_y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \exp \left\{ - \frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)} \left[ \frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{\sigma_x^2}
-2 \rho \frac{(x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y)}{\sigma_x \sigma_y} + \frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{\sigma_y^2} \right] \right\}$$

then it is easy to see that

$$f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, dy = \text{const.} \cdot \exp \left[ - \frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{2 \sigma_x^2} \right]. $$
We must have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx = 1$$ so
$$f(x) =  \frac{1}{\sigma_x\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left[ - \frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{2 \sigma_x^2} \right]. $$

Source:  Papoulis, **Probability, Random Variables, and Stochastic Processes**, Second Edition, p. 127.